How to compress file into bz2 using stream i Nodejs?
I'd like to download some CSV files from S3 bucket, archive and compress them into file-name.tar.gz and then upload to another S3 bucket.
My server doesn't have storage/disk. It only has memory. So I need to use stream in Node.js to handle this task.
I am a newbie with Node.js and stream. As I understand about the stream flow, it handle each chunk data (download from S3, archive & compress, upload to S3 immediately), then it handle the next chunk. It will not use much memory.
For archive, I use tar-stream lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-stream
For compress, I use Gzip of Zlib.
My code work well. There are 9 CSV files. Two largest files is 9GB and 3GB. Another files   has only less than 500MB. It takes about 6 minutes to completes:
const {
  ListObjectsV2Command,
  GetObjectCommand,
  HeadObjectCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { PassThrough, pipeline, Transform } = require("stream");
const tar = require("tar-stream");
const constantService = require("./services/constant");
const s3Service = require("./services/s3");
const zlib = require("zlib");

async function getFileSize(s3Client, bucket, key) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };
  const headObject = await s3Client.send(new HeadObjectCommand(params));
  return headObject.ContentLength;
}

// Download CSVs from S3, compress them and upload it to alliance S3 bucket using stream
async function streamProcess(
  s3Client,
  sourceBucket,
  folderPath,
  destinationBucket
) {
  // Set highWaterMark to control buffer size
  const passThrough = new PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS,
  }); // Create passthrough stream
  const pack = tar.pack({
    highWaterMark: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS,
  }); // Create tar pack stream
  const zipStream = zlib.createGzip({
    chunkSize: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS,
  });

  pack.on("error", (err) => {
    throw new Error(`Pack stream error: ${err.message}`);
  });

  passThrough.on("error", (err) => {
    throw new Error(`PassThrough stream error: ${err.message}`);
  });
  passThrough.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log("PassThrough chunk with length: ", chunk.length);
  });

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: destinationBucket,
    Key: folderPath.destinationKey,
    Body: passThrough,
  };

  const uploadPromise = s3Service.uploadLocalToS3(s3Client, uploadParams);

  const listObjectParams = {
    Bucket: sourceBucket,
    Prefix: folderPath.path,
  };

  const s3Objects = await s3Client.send(
    new ListObjectsV2Command(listObjectParams)
  );

  if (!s3Objects.Contents) {
    throw new Error(
      `No objects found in bucket ${sourceBucket} with prefix ${folderPath.path}`
    );
  }

  const files = s3Objects.Contents.map((obj) => obj.Key);

  for (const file of files) {
    const getObjectParams = { Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: file };
    const { Body } = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams));
    const fileSize = await getFileSize(s3Client, sourceBucket, file);

    Body.on("error", (err) => {
      throw new Error(`Body stream error: ${err.message}`);
    });

    Body.on("data", (chunk) => {
      console.log("Body chunk with chunk length: ", chunk.length);
    });

    const entry = pack.entry(
      {
        name: `${folderPath.name}/${file.replace(folderPath.path, "")}`,
        size: fileSize,
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(`Entry error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    );
    pipeline(Body, entry, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Pipeline body & entry error: ${err.message}`);
      }
    });
  }

  pack.finalize();
  pipeline(pack, zipStream, passThrough, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(
        `Pipeline pack & bz2 & passthrough error: ${err.message}`
      );
    }
  });
  await uploadPromise;
}

// Main function
(async () => {
  const alliance = constantService.ALLIANCES.find(
    (alliance) => alliance.name === process.env.ALLIANCE_NAME
  );
  const sourceBucket = process.env.ALLIANCE_TMP_S3_BUCKET;
  const folderPaths = [
    {
      name: "rent",
      path: `test/tmp/rent/`,
      destinationKey: "rent_EE.tar.bz2",
    },
    {
      name: "master",
      path: `test/tmp/master/`,
      destinationKey: "master_EE.tar.bz2",
    },
  ];
  const destinationBucket = alliance.s3BucketName;
  const s3Client = s3Service.getS3Client();

  const promises = folderPaths.map((folderPath) => {
    return streamProcess(s3Client, sourceBucket, folderPath, destinationBucket);
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
})();


But the requirement change, the client want to compress file with bzip2 algorithm instead of gzip.
Because the zlib doesn't support bzip2, I use another lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressjs.
const {
  ListObjectsV2Command,
  GetObjectCommand,
  HeadObjectCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const { PassThrough, pipeline, Transform } = require("stream");
const tar = require("tar-stream");
const constantService = require("./services/constant");
const s3Service = require("./services/s3");
const compressjs = require("compressjs");


// Transform stream for Bzip2 compression using compressjs
class Bzip2Transform extends Transform {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }

  _transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    try {
      const compressed = compressjs.Bzip2.compressFile(chunk);
      callback(null, compressed);
    } catch (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
  }
}


async function getFileSize(s3Client, bucket, key) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };
  const headObject = await s3Client.send(new HeadObjectCommand(params));
  return headObject.ContentLength;
}

// Download CSVs from S3, compress them and upload it to alliance S3 bucket using stream
async function streamProcess(s3Client, sourceBucket, folderPath, destinationBucket) {
  // Set highWaterMark to control buffer size
  const passThrough = new PassThrough({ highWaterMark: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS }); // Create passthrough stream
  const pack = tar.pack({ highWaterMark: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS }); // Create tar pack stream
  const bzip2 = new Bzip2Transform({ highWaterMark: constantService.HIGH_WATER_MARK_COMPRESS }); // Create Bzip2 transform stream
  pack.on('error', (err) => {
    throw new Error(`Pack stream error: ${err.message}`);
  });
  bzip2.on('error', (err) => {
    throw new Error(`bzip2 stream error: ${err.message}`);
  });
  passThrough.on('error', (err) => {
    throw new Error(`PassThrough stream error: ${err.message}`);
  });
  // passThrough.on('data', (chunk) => {
  //   console.log('PassThrough chunk with length: ', chunk.length);
  // });

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: destinationBucket,
    Key: folderPath.destinationKey,
    Body: passThrough,
  };

  const uploadPromise = s3Service.uploadLocalToS3(s3Client, uploadParams);

  const listObjectParams = {
    Bucket: sourceBucket,
    Prefix: folderPath.path,
  };

  const s3Objects = await s3Client.send(new ListObjectsV2Command(listObjectParams));

  if (!s3Objects.Contents) {
    throw new Error(`No objects found in bucket ${sourceBucket} with prefix ${folderPath.path}`);
  }

  const files = s3Objects.Contents.map((obj) => obj.Key);

  for (const file of files) {
    const getObjectParams = { Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: file };
    const { Body } = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams));
    const fileSize = await getFileSize(s3Client, sourceBucket, file);

    Body.on('error', (err) => {
      throw new Error(`Body stream error: ${err.message}`);
    });

    // Body.on('data', (chunk) => {
    //   console.log('Body chunk with chunk length: ', chunk.length);
    // });

    const entry = pack.entry({ name: `${folderPath.name}/${file.replace(folderPath.path, '')}`, size: fileSize}, Body, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Entry error: ${err.message}`);
      } 
    });
    pipeline(
      Body,
      entry,
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw new Error(`Pipeline body & entry error: ${err.message}`);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  pack.finalize();
  pipeline(
    pack,
    bzip2,
    passThrough,
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(`Pipeline pack & bz2 & passthrough error: ${err.message}`);
      }
    }
  );
  await uploadPromise;
}

// Main function
(async () => {
  const alliance = constantService.ALLIANCES.find(
    (alliance) => alliance.name === process.env.ALLIANCE_NAME
  );
  const sourceBucket = process.env.ALLIANCE_TMP_S3_BUCKET;
  const folderPaths = [
    {
      name: "rent",
      path: `test/tmp/rent/`,
      destinationKey: "rent_EE.tar.bz2",
    },
    {
      name: "master",
      path: `test/tmp/master/`,
      destinationKey: "master_EE.tar.bz2",
    },
  ];
  const destinationBucket = alliance.s3BucketName;
  const s3Client = s3Service.getS3Client();

  const promises = folderPaths.map((folderPath) => {
    return streamProcess(s3Client, sourceBucket, folderPath, destinationBucket);
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
})();

It works well with the small file (<500 MB).
It takes 1h30m for only 3GB file.
It failed when I run full files (3GB & 9GB) after 5 minutes run: Body stream error: aborted
My server resource: 1 CPU & 1GB memory
I use another lib for bzip2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bzip2
But it still same error.

I think your server's memory is the bottleneck here, since it has to keep chunk of raw csv data as-well as compressed one in memory, so 1GB is way too small for 9GB input (even 3GB ?).

You might be able to compress 3GB file in memory with help of storage/disk + swap file

Perhaps it is due to the nature of bzip2 algorithm, which is much more memory intensive than gzip. I'm not sure you can use t2.micro or similar to process 9gb input for bzip2. I Would rather add more resources (operating memory, or swap space) or event offload it an external service to compress.

@PavloSobchuk "much more memory intensive"? Maybe through the optics of 25 years ago. Memory requirement for compression is barely 8MiB for the biggest block size (which is 900k). There is a section in the documentation that explains it. Of course, that assumes you don't hoard the compressed result in memory until the whole process is done, but stream it (although not doing so is not a fault of the algorithm).
